# App on second screen does not come back to main screen after disconnection

Tags: macos, screen

Using macos Big Sur on a MBP.
I use a second screen, pluggued on hdmi. I place some windows/apps on the 2nd screen.
But when I disconnect/unplug the 2nd screen (to work on the canape for example), the apps do not come back to the main screen, as it does on Windows. And I can still move the mouse to the 2nd screen, even it is disconnected.
Is there a good way to simply disconnect and work on only one screen ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57620/macbook-unplugged-from-external-monitor-thinks-its-still-the-secondary-desktop

Just type Cmd + Brightness Up and it comes back to normal. And when the screen is plugued, the windows are redispatched as before. Nice... But why this shortcut ?